# Most efficient way to structure content likes in SQL

Tags: sql

There are posts which I want to be able to be liked.

I was thinking of creating a separate table in my database called "votes"

`FEILDS: UID | POST ID | Date of Like`

`DATA .:1337 | Post66 .| 14032049 . .` < raw time from 1970 - is this a bad practice too?

instead of inserting an array into a field such as "liked content" under the users data - or "users who've liked" under the content.

Is this the best way to implement such a feature?
It would help to limit the amount of times a user can like the post presumably, however is seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: A separate table Is the approach I would use, minus your dateformat.  It is best to use a standard date format and storing timezone is good as well unless you will always know what it will be or always make sure to convert it.

Comment: I would call the table `UserLikes` and give it a primary key.  That's my only suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It seems to make sense, why would you want to implement the logic stopping the user voting more than once in database? The enforcement of some business rules by usage of foreign keys etc. is trademark of database developer, application developers put the logic in middle tier.